# Openlayers GeoJSON reprojection issue 4.3.3 vs 5.3.0

Tags: openlayers, geojson

While switching from ol 4.3.3 to 5.3.0 I encountered a problem. The WMS layers work as I expected (display in the right location), geojson data don't.  I read all the data from the same service in both ol versions, everything that is changed is class notation ( I mean here: new ol.format.geojson() to new GeoJSON()). The part of code responsible for geojson import is as follows:

```
var dJson = (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(response1.data, {
                                 featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
                                dataProjection: 'EPSG:2180' 
                            });

var source = new VectorSource({ features: dJson});
```

Result data appear in  location (wrong one) that suggests that source data were not projected to epsg:3857 from epsg:2180. In the old version they display in Poland, now near the equator in Africa.
EPSG2180 is decleared in code ahead via proj4 lib.
What am I missing?

Comment: The main difference between the versions is you need to register proj4 after settings defs https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj_proj4.html

Comment: As @Mike pointed out, see section **Changes in proj4 integration** in OL5 release notes: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v5.0.0

Comment: It works! Thank You both:)